# Variation of Majorana action

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action, variational-calculus, majorana-fermions

In the Supergravity book by Freedman, Van Proeyen on page 59 it states that the Majorana action is 
$$S[\Psi]=-\frac{1}{2}\int d^Dx\bar{\Psi}(\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}-m)\Psi.\tag{3.88}$$
After varying the action you get a term for $\delta\bar{\Psi}$ and one for $\delta\Psi$. In the book it says that after a Majorana flip and partial integration you see that these terms are the same and you get the Dirac action.
If I vary the action I get
$$\delta S[\Psi]=-\frac{1}{2}\int d^Dx \left[ \delta \bar{\Psi}(\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}-m)\Psi+\bar{\Psi}(\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}-m)\delta\Psi\right]$$
If I then do a Majorana flip in the second term it will be
$$-\delta\bar{\Psi}(\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}-m)\Psi$$ and $\delta S[\Psi]$ would just be zero. Probably I'm doing something wrong with the Majorana flip applied to the variation of the field

Comment: You have to integrate the second term by parts as you have ${\bar\Psi}\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\delta\Psi$.

Comment: @Jon  Oh you mean before I do the variation?

Comment: Oh I see, because I have the derivative of the variation

Comment: No, after the variation and integrating by parts you will get $(-\partial{\bar\Psi}\cdot\gamma-m{\bar\Psi})\delta\Psi$.

Comment: That is right. You are done.

Comment: @Jon Oh yes I was stupid Haha Thank you!